# How i can stop already sent email?

Tags: email, email-spoofing

I have a Gmail account. Unfortunately I have sent an email from my Gmail account. How I can stop or back this email ?

Comment: Not sure this is a security question.

Comment: Send it to superUser.SE

Comment: If you happen to be Goldman Sachs and the recipient has a gmail address, you can ask Google to [block the recipient from being able to view the message](http://arstechnica.com/business/2014/07/goldman-sachs-demands-google-unsend-one-of-its-e-mails/)

Answer (score 3):

**It depends on your gmail account settings**. Not sure if you have enabled the Undo Send option for your account. If you haven't then it is not possible to stop the sent mail.

1. Go to **account settings** in your gmail account by clicking the settings icon.
2. click **Settings**
3. click the **Labs** tab
4. Check the **Undo Send** option

[image]

If Enabled already, then you will have the option to undo the mail you've sent. If not, you can not undo your sent mail.

I would suggest you to have this option enabled since it might pay you off someday like this one.